# PHP while loop break after sent

Tags: php, mysql

I sent a PHP infinite loop and I can't stop it, I deleted the file on the server but it still continues to enter data into the DATABASE, is there any way to deactivate it?

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `gancxadebebi` 
($keys) 

VALUES 

($values)";
$var = 0;
while(true){
    sleep(1);
    $r = mysqli_query($c, $q);
    if($r){
        echo 'success';
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
    ++$var;
    echo $var;
    
    if($var == '100000'){
        break;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `$var == '100000'` compare an integer against a string? (OK, there might be some auto casting here but still it isn't clean.) And a `for` loop might make things clearer here. But still it isn't infinite. It just iterates 100000 times.

Comment: How to stop the process depends on your OS. In Windows you can use the Task Manager to locate and end the process. In Unix and Linux you can use `ps` (probably with the `ax` switch) to get a list of processes, identify the one in there and use `kill` (probably with the `-9` flag) with the process id you got from the `ps` list. Or restart the computer, that'll be the brute force method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a development machine. If that is the case, just restart the web-server to terminate the PHP script. If you are using apache, that would look like:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Don't run this command when you are working in a production machine.